# Extend Identity Server 4 Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a .Net-Core project which uses Identity Server 4 as a token server.   Currently, I have set up Identity server 4 to handle some payments through Coinbase.   I would like to post back some information back to my api from IdentityServer.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthorizeTransaction(AuthorizeTransaction transactionInfo)
{
    transactionInfo.Transaction.Type = "send";

    try
    {
        var resp = await this._coinbaseOAuthClient
                        .WithHeader("CB-2FA-TOKEN", transactionInfo.TwoFactorCode)
                                .Transactions
                                     .SendMoneyAsync(transactionInfo.AccountId, transactionInfo.Transaction);

        this.PostBackTransactionData(resp.Data)
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("CreateTransaction", transactionInfo);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}

protected void PostBackTransactionData(Transaction data)
{
    //TODO: Inject api from DI
    var confirmTransactionEndpoint = "https://localhost:44377/api/transactions/confirm-payment";
    var client = new FlurlClient();

    confirmTransactionEndpoint.WithClient(client).PostJsonAsync(data);           
}
```

On my Api I store the data I need in my Database however I'm having trouble on figuring out how I can Authenticate this request.

Normally when you want to verify an application you'd use something like Identity server, overkill to have another token server to verify my token server.

What is a secure way to validate that the request came from my token server (Identity Server 4)?

Comment: IdentityServer could also be a client to your API, that would be my recommendation. It will be secure, and act like just another client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this is to use the in-built tools from Identity Server to issue a client JWT and set that as the bearer token to the request back into the API's.

I setup a new Identity Client that contained a specific scope for accessing the API's from Identity and used this client to self issue the above JWT.  Then within the API's, I created a new authorization policy for this scope and applied that to certain endpoints within the API.

For example

**In Identity Server**
You can inject IdentityServerTools into your class.  This is pre registered for you and is part of the IdentityServer4 namespace

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
  private readonly IdentityServerTools _identityServerTools;
  public SomeService(IdentityServerTools identityServerTools) 
  {
    _identityServerTools = identityServerTools;
  }

  private async Task<string> CreateTokenAsync()
  {
    // Get client for JWT
    var idpClient = _dbContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientId == SomeClientId);
    // Get scopes to set in JWT
    var scopes = idpClient.AllowedScopes.Select(s => s.Scope).ToArray();
    // Use in-built Identity Server tools to issue JWT
    var token = await _identityServerTools.IssueClientJwtAsync(idpClient.ClientId, idpClient.AccessTokenLifetime, scopes, new[] { "Some Api Name"})
  }
}
```

Then set this token as the bearer token on your request.

**In your API**
Now to authorize this request back in your API's setup an authorization policy on Startup

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => 
{
   options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", policy => {
    policy.RequireScope("ScopeName")
   })
})
```

And then on your endpoint in your API's add the following

```
[Authorize("PolicyName")]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing it out now. I'll give you the check when I get it working

Comment: Just as a heads up, you don't need to create an explicitly create a client, the tools will create a token for you based on the params passed in.